# Too many positional arguments are given

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi there smart people,

I have a small program where a combobox should be updated with a new list, depending on a User entry, when a Button is clicked.

Infact I would assume that no arguments need to be given since the called functions "gets" the user entries and then updates the combobox. No additional external Info needed.

Unfortunatley I get the Error:

`TypeError:Func_Update_MA() takes 1positional argument but 2 were given.`

How can I solve this issue?
To be honest I dont really get the whole "self" thing but I tried pretty much every combination of using self, not using it and combining it with something like args* or kwargs** (another mystery to me)

If you need more code I will provide it off course.

Thanks alot in advance!

```
class Class_MA_Win(): 

    def __init__(self, Win_MA_Sel, Cockpit_Win):  

        Btt_Update_MA = Button(self.Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win, text="Liste Updaten")
        Btt_Update_MA.bind("<Button-1>",self.Func_Update_MA)
        Btt_Update_MA.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)


    def Func_Update_MA(self):
        Entry_name = self.Ent_first_name_MA.get()
        Entry_lastname = self.Ent_last_name_MA.get()
        Entry_ID = self.Ent_ID_MA.get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use `widget.bind(...)`, it will return an event object with a number of attributes describing the event. This is then passed to your func `Func_Update_MA` which accepts no argument, thus the error.

To solve this, simply accept the event as an arg:

```
def Func_Update_MA(self,event=None):
    ...
```

Also you mentioned about `args` and `kwargs` but you seem to wrongly position the asterisks. The correct is `*args` and `**kwargs`, like so:

```
def Func_Update_MA(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```